# Python win32com EXCEL return None

Tags: python, windows, excel, win32com

this's my first question and I'm a little bad at python and english too, I hope you understand...

I'm trying to cycle through the rows in an excel column. The last lines return None, what's wrong with my code?

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

for n in range(1,200):
    n=repr(n)
    cell = "b"+ n
    lis = (excel.ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet.Range(cell))
    if lis != "":
        print(lis)
    else:
        print("There's nothing here")
```

It prints None for the white rows, instead of There's nothing here.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `None != ""` since empty row is obviously returned as None, it does not match your if... change it to if `lis!= None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`None != ""`.  You should be testing with the `is not` operator:

```
if lis is not None:
```

Note that you shouldn't be using `!= None` as others have suggested.  [From PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.

EDIT: as per the discussion in the comments, `lis` should be assigned as follows:

```
lis = excel.ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet.Range(cell).GetValue()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try but this's the result:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/************/Read.py", line 8, in <module>
    lis = (excel.ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet.Range(cells))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Activesheet'

Comment: Sorry my error, the file xls was closed... But with your solution it prints None for white cells instead of my string....

Comment: @user2903746 does it print "None" or does it print some blank string?

Comment: Only None. If I put "if lis is none" instead of is not, it prints only my string for all the rows.

Comment: @user2903746 I wonder if it's a case sensitivity issue.  Can you try with `cell = "B"+ n`

Comment: Same results, nothing changes in the output.

Comment: @user2903746 what is the result of `print excel.ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet.Range("B"+20)` (assuming `B20` is empty)?

Comment: I used ("B"+"20"), else it gives me TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: @user2903746 is it the string "None" or None?  `print type(excel.ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet.Range("B20"))`

Comment: <class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'>

Comment: @user2903746 what does `excel.ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet.Range("B20").GetValue()` give you?  You may need to change `lis` to `lis = excel.ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet.Range(cell).GetValue()`

Comment: With .GetValue() it works,thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Because an empty row will return a `None` value instead of an empty string.

So, compare it to the `None` type instead:

```
if lis is not None:
    print(lis)
else:
    print("There's nothing here")
```

This should work just fine.

Comment: From PEP8: `Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.`

Comment: Edited, sorry. I forgot that.